# Looking for another word of effect, result .

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, synonyms

I am looking for word which signifies effect, as from 'cause and effect' and you do something and you get the result, the consequence of it. The word I'm looking from rhymes with 'percussion' but am not able to remember it. I'll attempt to share couple of examples which will attempt to illustrate what I want to say -

1. This is from a popular Indian film 'Karma' iconic [dialog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4KQpRhk9AE) between Anupam Kher (Dr. Dang) and Rana Vikram Pratap Singh (Dilip Kumar) . Rana Vikram Pratap Singh slaps Dr. Dang and Dr. Dang replies -

Did you hear the echo of the slap ? Now you will hear the echo of the echo. Till you are alive you will hear the echo.

2. The second is aftershocks. Like when you have an earthquake, after the main earthquake subsides, you still have aftershocks which happen.

I am looking for a word which tells that due to a decision or something which has happened 'say the financial crisis of 2008 in US' the effects were visible all over the world and still continue to this day, also it has resulted into quite a bit of unexpected behavior from many places.

I know there is a single word/phrase which tells all of the above, but am not getting it atm. Can somebody help ?

Comment: *Outcome? Upshot? Conclusion?*

Comment: I think you’re looking for ***repercussion***

Comment: @Jim had answered my own question/query at the same time, just few seconds earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

Repercussion - This is the word I was looking for. Sorry if I wasn't good at explaining it.

Comment: To increase your answer's potential usefulness to other readers, please consider adding a dictionary definition of the word _repercussion_ to it that might help explain why it was suitable for the context you asked about. Failing that, consider deleting this answer and instead editing your original question to note that repercussion is the word you were looking for.